# Can't use dropwizard-core classes

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

I am using m2e plugin with Eclipse. I have created a Maven project and added the dropwizard-core dependency in the POM as stated in http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/.

However, I can't export specific dropwizard-core classes. For example, when I

> import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration;

I get an error that the class cannot be resolved. However, just plain

```
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.*;
```

works.

Additionally, when I try to inspect the dropwizard-core jar inside the "Maven dependencies", I can see the "Configuration" class there. I just can't extend it even when importing the above-mentioned package. And this unresolvable class happens for all the other classes that are inside the jar. Is there any step that I missed?

By the way, I'm using the following:
1. ADT (but I was able to replicate the issue using the standard Eclipse)
2. Java SDK 7 and JRE 7
3. Mac

Comment: This looks like an integration issue between Eclipse and the Maven plugin. The best way to eliminate Dropwizard from the problem is to build outside of Eclipse on the command line. If that works then the problem lies with your IDE. Consider changing to [Intellij Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: Thanks! That helped me figure out the issue. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the jar files in ~/.m2/repository have been corrupted. This issue has been solved by deleting everything in the repository and do a:

> mvn clean install

All the classes can be resolved now.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is more likely that you need to add the dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```